# Entity Exception: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details

Tags: entity-framework

This exception happened here:

```
public void updateAccount(CommonLayer.Account account)
    {
        Entity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296058
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest) +796
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest) +395
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest) +137
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName) +230
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso) +12
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) +60
>      System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) +10
>      System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) +83

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you add more information about your model?

Comment: what info do you need?

Comment: I'm not sure. but perhaps this happen because you didn't use using().

Comment: can you answer with example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed more info because I want to now is you application web or desktop. If you want to use **EDM** you should to use using() code block.
For example:

```
 public void SaveUser(User oldUser)
    {
        using (MyEntity myEntity= new MyEntity ())
        {
            var user = myEntity.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == oldUser.UserId).Single();
            user.UserName = oldUser.UserName;
            // and other changes
            myEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```